# Non contractible path in $\Bbb{T}^n=\Bbb{R}^n/\Bbb{Z}^n.$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\gamma$ be a non contractible path in $\Bbb{T}^n=\Bbb{R}^n/\Bbb{Z}^n.$ Denote by $p$ the projection map.

I can choose a point $M\in \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $p(M)=\gamma(0).$ I can lift it to a path $\overline{\gamma}:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $\overline{\gamma}(0)=M$ and $p\circ \overline{\gamma}=\gamma.$

Now the problem is to "translate" the fact that $\gamma$ is non-contractible. Which means that $[\gamma]\ne 0\in \pi_1(\Bbb{T}^n)=\Bbb{Z}^n.$

For example, can I prove that the length of $\gamma$ is greater than $\Vert \overline{\gamma}(1)-\overline{\gamma}(0)\Vert ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to show is that $\gamma$ is contractible if and only if $\bar \gamma(0) = \bar \gamma(1)$.

For the forward implication, you assume that $\gamma$ is contractible, which means that there exists a continuous function
$$ H : [0,1]\times [0,1] \to \mathbb T^n$$
such that
$$ H(s,0) = H(s,1) , \ \ \ \ \ H(0,t) = \gamma(t), \ \ \ \ \ H(1,t) = {\rm constant}$$
It is a good idea to consider $\bar H$, the lift of $H$ to $\mathbb R^n$ extending $\bar \gamma$. Then you could consider the continuous map
$$ [0,1] \to  \mathbb R^n, \\ s \mapsto \bar H(s,1) - \bar H(s,0).$$
You can then think about how you  might argue that

- the image of this map is contained in $\mathbb Z^n \subset \mathbb R^n$;
- $\bar H(1,1) - \bar H (1,0) = 0$;
- $\bar \gamma(1) = \bar \gamma (0)$.

The reverse implication is much easier: $\mathbb R^n$ is contractible, so if $\bar \gamma$ is a loop, then it is null-homotopic in $\mathbb R^n$. Then project down...

Comment: Thanks, I need to work on your answer. Do we have $\bar \gamma(1)-\bar \gamma(0)\in \Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Alex Yes, and to prove this, consider $p \circ \bar \gamma (1)$ and $p \circ\bar \gamma (0)$...

Comment: hum, I have $p\circ\bar\gamma (1)=\gamma(1)=p(M')$ and $p\circ \bar\gamma(0)=\gamma(0)=p(M).$ We have $p(M)-p(M')=0$ because $\gamma$ is a closed path (I forgot to mention that but it was implicit I suppose). Therefore $p(M-M')=0$ so that $M-M'\in \Bbb{Z}^n.$ Finally $\bar\gamma (1)-\bar\gamma(0)\in \Bbb{Z}^n.$ Correct ?

Comment: @Alex Yes, correct. Now apply this argument to $\bar H(s,1) - \bar H(s,0)$ for arbitrary $s$...